# Return user Highest number and Unique number in table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, collections

I has table user_data: 
[image]

I want return user has Highest number and Unique number! 
=> User id=5, name= E, number=3
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What exactly was the problem?

Comment: just use max() order by and limit.

Comment: Please post text rather than images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`number` FROM `user_data` GROUP BY `number` HAVING COUNT(`number`) = 1 ORDER BY `number` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Quite similar with the Suresh's answer

Answer (score 1):

As per the given data above please find the query as :

```
 SELECT number , id , NAME FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) , number,id,NAME FROM `user_data` GROUP BY number HAVING COUNT(*) < 2 ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1) tab;
```

This will give you the required result.
Check this!!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the higher number by querying all the distinct user and order them by ID and return the first element

```
User::distinct()->orderBy('id')->first()
```